# Google Compute Engine: Get specific data associated with a Google Compute Engine virtual machine instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using the below command to display all data associated with a Google Compute Engine virtual machine instance.

> `gcloud compute instances describe <instance>`

I want only specific information like "tags" , "machine-type" instead of whole information.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can add grep to the command as follows:

```
gcloud compute instances describe INSTANCE_NAME --zone INSTANCE'S_ZONE | grep machineType:

gcloud compute instances describe INSTANCE_NAME --zone INSTANCE'S_ZONE | grep tags:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can you the format option to the only the information you want.

> gcloud compute instances list --format='value(name, tags.items,
>   machineType)'

You can use table to make output prettier

> gcloud compute instances list --format='table[](name, tags.items,
>   machineType)'

To see the list attributes:

> gcloud compute instances list --format=flattened

To learn more about formats:

> gcloud topic formats